# How to decode the Cuneiform ORACC data?

Tags: ancient, datasets, sumerian, cuneiform, akkadian

I just found [this](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/ogsl/signlist/index.html), the "OGSL Signlist" for Cuneiform. Remove the frame to get [here](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/ogsl/signlist/home.html). I click on a sign like [`A.EDIN`](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/ogsl/signlist/l0065/o0000666/index.html) and see this:

> Values:eribₓ; eru₄; erua; erum₄; ummuₓ; ummudₓ.
>
> for |A.EDIN| as ED form of ummu₃ see Civil ARES 4, 120

What does that mean?

I've looked around for the conventions around Cuneiform but don't know where the README is.

A more complex example is [`A`](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/ogsl/signlist/l0065/o0000087/index.html)...

What do we see here?

Looking at the raw ORACC JSON, I see this (2 examples out of a lot):

```
"A": {
  "values": [
    "ʾu₄",
    "a",
    "aia₂",
    "aya₂",
    "barₓ",
    "buniŋₓ",
    "burₓ",
    "dur₅",
    "duru₅",
    "e₄",
    "ea",
    "ebir₃",
    "emₓ",
    "epir₃",
    "eš₁₀",
    "ŋa₁₀",
    "ia₁₀",
    "id₅",
    "me₅",
    "mu₁₄",
    "sedₓ",
    "šegₓ",
    "ṭur₅",
    "ya₁₀"
  ],
  "gdl": [
    {
      "s": "A"
    }
  ],
  "uphase": "1",
  "uname": "CUNEIFORM SIGN A",
  "utf8": "",
  "hex": "x12000"
},
...
"|GA.NI|": {
  "values": [
    "gar₁₀",
    "gara₁₀"
  ],
  "gdl": [
    {
      "c": "|GA.NI|",
      "seq": [
        {
          "s": "GA"
        },
        {
          "o": "beside"
        },
        {
          "s": "NI"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "utf8": "",
  "hex": "x120B5.x1224C"
},
```

Notice that for `A`, the sign is . If I then search one of the *values* like [dur5](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/cgi-bin/cuneify?input=dur5) using the Cuneify tool, I get the same sign, .

Looking at `|GA.NI|`, I see there are two signs,  and  making . Does this mean the "key" in the JSON (or the name in the dictionary) is referencing each isolated glyph? And then the "values" array are all the different pronunciations that evaluate to these glyphs?

Or what does the key and value mean?

Another more complex example is:

```
"|A.GAN₂@t|": {
  "deprecated": "1",
  "gdl": [
    {
      "c": "|A.GAN₂@t|",
      "seq": [
        {
          "s": "A"
        },
        {
          "o": "beside"
        },
        {
          "form": "GAN₂@t",
          "mods": [
            {
              "b": "GAN₂"
            },
            {
              "m": "t"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Notice the `@` in the key. And there is no Cuneiform glyph in here. What does this one mean?

Basically I'm trying to figure out how they are encoding the glyphs into pronunciations and other things, but I don't see what they mean, and don't know where the docs are.

Comment: I'd recommend reading a good introductory textbook on Sumerian (or Akkadian or Hittite, depending what type of cuneiform you're interested in). It's hard to explain an entire writing system used for multiple languages across thousands of years in a single SE answer.

Comment: There's gotta be a quick answer to this, otherwise how am I supposed to use their data? I'm just looking for the meaning of these fields, that's it. They can't mean that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A* is the conventional name for a particular cuneiform glyph, typically its most common or best-known pronunciation. But the sign *A* can be read as *a*, *aya₂*, *e₄*, *ea*, *ŋa₁₀*, or many others. The JSON is mapping the name to a list of all these possible readings.

Sometimes, though, a cuneiform glyph is made from other glyphs joined together. There are a variety of different ways to join them; a dot between the sign names, for example, means that they're written one after another (for example the sign *IŠTAR* = *|U.DAR|*, *U* followed by *DAR*), while a cross means that the second is inside the first (*SISKUR* = *|AMAR×ŠE|*, *ŠE* enclosed by *AMAR*), and so on. In ORACC, compound glyphs are transcribed with bars on either side.

This can be used to build up more complicated glyphs, like the *|A.GAN₂@t|* you mentioned: this means *A* next to *GAN₂*, slanted at 45 degrees (*tenû* in Akkadian). But this particular transcription is deprecated; the preferred name for *GAN₂ tenû* is *KAR₂*. And this particular combination, *|A.KAR₂|*, I haven't been able to find in my usual sign lists, so it's probably not in Unicode either.

You can find a basic overview of the transcription conventions ORACC uses [on their website](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/doc/help/editinginatf/primer/inlinetutorial/index.html), but I'd recommend finding a good textbook for whichever language you're interested in (probably Sumerian or Akkadian), which will go into more detail on how exactly cuneiform writing works.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Would have taken forever to figure this out. So the CAPS is just a common name, but the lowercase are all the keys to the unicode cuneiform glyph? And it sounds like the CAPS also adds some extra metadata (nesting, next-to, or slanting, etc.)? This isn't included in the lowercase "keys" then...

Comment: Ah that link is great, just what I was looking for!

Comment: What is a good _free_ sumerian (or akkadian, 2nd preference) book online? If none exist then what is your goto resource?

Comment: @LancePollard In Sumerian studies, all-caps is conventionally used for sign names and lowercase for pronunciation. But this varies across languages; in Akkadian, for example, all-caps is also used to transcribe logograms.

Comment: (And in Hittite, there's a distinction between all-caps roman and all-caps italic, and the latter is pronunciation rather than sign names—it's a bit convoluted, and very language-dependent.)

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @LancePollard As far as textbooks, I've never found a free online Sumerian book I was particularly happy with, but you could potentially ask it as a reference-request question.

Comment: @LancePollard: For Akkadian, Huehnergard's classic _A Grammar Of Akkadian_ is nowadays available as [a free PDF on academia.edu](https://www.academia.edu/234695/2011_A_Grammar_of_Akkadian_3rd_edition_). For Sumerian, Foxvog's _Introduction to Sumerian Grammar_ is available [as a PDF from CDLI](https://cdli.ucla.edu/pubs/cdlp/cdlp0002_20160104.pdf) and gives a quite modern view of the language (in some respects departing a bit from earlier interpretations e.g. regarding verbal conjugation — not necessarily a bad thing, but worth keeping in mind).

Comment: How do you guys know so much, this is so cool :) :) :) Your depth of knowledge is inspiring, everyone who's been answering these questions and I'm sure more.

Comment: @LancePollard: Well, it helps to take a course or two (or three or four or five) at the university. :) Online self-learning is all well and fine, but it IME it really helps to have someone familiar with this stuff to teach you the basics of the language, point you at the most useful sources and explain the context and the relevant historical (both ancient and modern) background behind them.